# AS3 interclass variables

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I have a button, that's a class, say, Button. And a main document(class Main) where I can see all the changes in a text field, refreshed every frame (yeah, I don't like trace()). The button has a function of changing a variable that's used in main file. So when I press the button, that I add in the main file to the stage, I need it's function to work. Button class has this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function), further function adds to the var from main class. So if it did add, I would see the changes in the text field. I see changes made by an object I add directly, in the graphic editor, but no changes from the button, whose child I add. Variables are public. Functions are all public. So...

**Classes cannot exchange variables freely?**

**How do I change a variable via a function in a different class?**

Maybe I need to export and import var? I thought they all work as a united program that shares all public variables.

Main: I create var i, add Button child to stage and show i every frame =D

Button: When you press me, I add 1 to i =D

SherWood: Main, Y U don't show i, changed by Button? T_T

Code example:

http://piratepad.net/g5tTMFX4Bo

Comment: It would be good if you posted some code.

Comment: Code will be no good here as the understanding of classes fails.

Answer (score 1):

The Button (or any other class) has no built-in knowledge of the environment that is using it's instance.

The DisplayObject ancestors have the ability to check the parent container, and "main" container via `parent` and `stage` properties.

The programmers role (you) is to code flexible way to exchange information that any 2 (or more) classes needs to have, e.g. by exposing public methods/properties, dispatching events (that other party can listen) etc.

So, if the Main needs to know that Button (instance of Button) was clicked add listener to that button for click event, and then you will be able to do whatever you want e.g. add one to `i`

If Button then, for instance needs to present up-to-date value Main via exposed method can do that e.g. `myButton.setLabel("Value of i="+i);` which may be executed in aforementioned click listener,

regards

Comment: You mean I have to use Main class to write button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function)? What's the point in classes then? I thought to not overload the Main class I can write some code in Button class, then it will be applied to any of it's children. If I have to write the functions of Button in Main, then Button is no longer an effective class but just a picture. Isn't there anything like "import i(Button);" to import i value from defined class the moment it's executed? Obviously I need classes to always share vars, I count in 1, display results in another, then use by third...

Comment: "What's the point in classes then?" this shows how much you are missing the OOP knowledge, please search about the classes and OOP on the internet, the "classes" encapsulate some task/functionality, it is a building block of bigger system. I'm not trying to offend you but "go back to class".

Comment: I did, didn't find anything more than basics and came here to ask about it. I'm not trying to offend you but you're a type of person who'd rather say twice as much insulting than save up energy and just help. If you know - explain it and I'll appreciate it. Will take same text you used, but helpful one. PS many ppl give much more stupid question, which are answered here. I don't deserve it?

Comment: If you want to be in the pool of stupid question it's your choice - If you searched for classes and OOP and found nothing that basics its either you can't grasp the basics or haven't searched correctly. Moreover, it was daft question but I gave you an answer, use it, comment was about daft statement "what's the point in classes then?" to summarise: ALL medium to awsome aplication are using classes, ALL poor applications are not using them. Here is quick search on AS3 classes tutorials [KIRUPA AS3 Classes](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm)